# error "Inflate class android.widget.Button " when using styling on Android.Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, widget

I have this Button widget in Main.axml here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/WrittenText"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@style/MyButton"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is code in file /values/style:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
    <style name = "MyButton">
    <item name = "android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

That I can not apply for Button and always get error, how work with style?

Answer (score 1):

To apply the style , You need to use

`style="@style/MyButton"` instead of `android:textColor="@style/MyButton"`

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/WrittenText"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        style="@style/MyButton"/>
```

or you can directly apply the color like below (color can be from color file as well)

```
 android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
```

[`Apply style in xml xamarin`](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/general/style_a_button/)

Comment: there is said no identifier found for attribute "style"

Comment: I got, it seems first need create xml file in drawable file